# Segmentation fault on array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here's what I got:

```
char ***tokens;
*tokens=(char**)malloc((5)*sizeof(char*));
*tokens[4]=(char*)malloc((4)*sizeof(char));
```

And I got "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." At the third line.

The thing is, this is okay:

```
*tokens[0]=(char*)malloc((4)*sizeof(char));
```

And this is okay too:

```
*tokens[1]=(char*)malloc((4)*sizeof(char));
```

But this gives me segmentation fault:

```
*tokens[2]=(char*)malloc((4)*sizeof(char));
```

Or any number bigger than 2, why is that when the array should have a length of 5?

The idea is that I have a pointer that points to an array, each set of the array points to a string, so I can do something like this:

```
*tokens[0]="string";
```

And

```
(*tokens[0])[m]='s';
```

Comment: What's tokens variable definition?

Comment: There's no way that code compiled. Also, show the declaration of `tokens`, and [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: And show some relevant code.

Comment: how can you directly assain to `*tokens`?

Comment: `tokens` : uninitialize. and should be `(*tokens)[4]=(char*)malloc((4)*sizeof(char));`

Comment: On the second line you dereference `**tokens` but `**tokens` has never been initialized. Show more code and tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

What's exactly that you want to do? It seems that `char **tokens` would be a better solution to your problem.

In this moment, when you are doing

```
 *tokens=(char**)malloc((5)*sizeof(char*));
```

you are writing in the unallocated memory area pointed by the uninitialized variable tokens. Where it crashes afterwards then it is more or less random.

> The idea is that I have a pointer that points to an array, each set of
>   the array points to a string, so I can do something like this:
>
> `*tokens[0]="string";`

To which memory area do you think that variable will be pointing too?
I suggest you read [Pointer to const string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518107/pointer-to-const-string-in-c), which explains why `(*tokens[0])[m]='s';` would be illegal.
You should also learn about commands like `strcpy` and the like.